# Escaping special characters with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a script to generate char arrays from strings:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    echo -n "{" && echo -n "$1" | sed -r "s/((\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)|(\\\\[0-7]{1,3})|(\\\\?.))/'\1',/g" && echo "0}"
    shift
done
```

It works great as is:

```
$ wchar 'test\n' 'test\\n' 'test\123' 'test\1234' 'test\x12345'
{'t','e','s','t','\n',0}
{'t','e','s','t','\\','n',0}
{'t','e','s','t','\123',0}
{'t','e','s','t','\123','4',0}
{'t','e','s','t','\x12345',0}
```

But because sed considers each new line to be a brand new thing it doesn't handle actual newlines:

```
$ wchar 'test
> test'
{'t','e','s','t',
't','e','s','t',0}
```

How can I replace special characters (Tabs, newlines etc) with their escaped versions so that the output would be like so:

```
$ wchar 'test
> test'
{'t','e','s','t','\n','t','e','s','t',0}
```

**Edit:** Some ideas that almost work:

```
echo -n "{" && echo -n "$1" | sed -r ":a;N;;s/\\n/\\\\n/;$!ba;s/((\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)|(\\\\[0-7]{1,3})|(\\\\?.))/'\1',/g" && echo "0}"
```

Produces:

```
$ wchar 'test\n\\n\1234\x1234abg
test
test'
{test\n\\n\1234\x1234abg\ntest\ntest0}
```

While removing the `!`:

```
echo -n "{" && echo -n "$1" | sed -r ":a;N;;s/\\n/\\\\n/;$ba;s/((\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)|(\\\\[0-7]{1,3})|(\\\\?.))/'\1',/g" && echo "0}"
```

Produces:

```
$ wchar 'test\n\\n\1234\x1234abg
test
test'
{'t','e','s','t','\n','\\','n','\123','4','\x1234ab','g','\n','t','e','s','t',
test0}
```

This is close...

The first isn't performing the final replacement, and the second isn't correctly adding the last line

Comment: I would consider parsing the output of `od -c` instead of using `sed`

Comment: @JV, I wonder if your output is actually correct: `echo -ne 'test\x12345' | od -c` outputs `0000000   t   e   s   t 022   3   4   5`, interpreting `\x12` as a single char, not `\x12345`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: That's the shell prompt for a newline.

Comment: @glennjackman: I tested with GCC, while logic would presume to cut it off after 2 chars GCC reads them all in strings and chars, then does mod 0x100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pre-filter before passing to `sed`. Perl will do:

```
$ set -- 'test1
> test2'
$ echo -n "$1" | perl -0777 -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'
test1\ntest2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very convoluted solution, but might work for your needs. GNU awk 4.1

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
@include "join"
@include "ord"
BEGIN {
  RS = "\\\\(n|x..)"
  FS = ""
}
{
  for (z=1; z<=NF; z++)
    y[++x] = ord($z)<0x20 ? sprintf("\\x%02x",ord($z)) : $z
  y[++x] = RT
}
END {
  y[++x] = "\\0"
  for (w in y)
    y[w] = "'" y[w] "'"
  printf "{%s}", join(y, 1, x, ",")
}
```

Result

```
$ cat file
a
b\nc\x0a

$ ./foo.awk file
{'a','\x0a','b','\n','c','\x0a','\0'}
```

Comment: I like how this automatically handles escaping special characters - is there a way to remove the spaces between the output characters? That would basically do what I'm looking for

Comment: I'm talking about `od` on it's own - is there a way to remove the indentation used to split apart characters?

Comment: If the file contains an escape sequence (As read by GCC) it should be reproduced as a character. Input string `test\ntest\x0A` should output `{'t','e','s','t','\n','t','e','s','t','\x0A',0}` Yours splits the escape sequences into separate characters

Comment: Because `wchar_t` is 4 bytes on linux. Basically, if you want to create a static win32 unicode string on linux you need to create an array of characters - which is freaking annoying to do by hand.

Comment: That works. I have a version using double sed that works like this: `sed -r ':a;N;s/\n/\\n/;$!ba' | sed -r 's/((\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)|(\\[0-7]{1,3})|(\\?.))/'"'\1',/g"` I'm just annoyed I have to use double sed (Using a `;` breaks it for some reason)